# not finding js/kendo.all.min.js in js folder of free and open source Kendo UI core(want to implement splitter)

Tags: kendo-ui

I have downloaded Kendo UI core open and free source and tried to use splitter as in [this demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/splitter/index), but it did not work because in the `js` folder (from download) the `kendo.all.min.js` file is not present. Can anybody tell me what should I do? I tried using `kendo.core.min.js` but it did not work.

I don't want to use the CDN URL `http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.416/js/kendo.all.min.js` in my project.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 16):

The **kendo.all.min.js** is available only in the commercial Kendo UI Professional package. Kendo UI core ships with **kendo.ui.core.min.js** which is the file you should use.